# Cursor over WinForm control (c#, WinForm 4.0)

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

What is the **easiest** way to determine if my current cursor position is over a particular (WinForm) control?

I can - of course - calculate the control's position and then check whether the cursor position is within this rectangel. But maybe there is something already existing for this....

I **cannot** use `OnMouseOver` event for this, because the decisions must take place within (another) event. In order to further explain here is what I do (in pseudo code). The problem is, when I start the drag event, then move to another control (outside this), release the mouse to finish the drop, the context menu is displayed on the "wrong" control (the drop target). This is what I want to avoid....

```
 private void TableControlMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        // this is a User control with some sub controls 

        // when selected start drag and drop
        if (SOMEConditions)
        {
            // start drag and drop operation
            DragAndDropWrapper dragAndDropWrapper = new DragAndDropWrapper(this.ObjectsToDrag, this);
            this._subControl.DoDragDrop(dragAndDropWrapper, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }

        // context menu

        // check should go here
        // something like "is pt still over "this" or over the drag target ...
        Point pt = this._subControl.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
        this._myContextMenu.Show(this._subControl, pt);
    }
```

-- as of today --
See below for the extension method I am using at the moment ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best solution I have found so far. Actually it is pretty easy (as always once you know how to do it ;-) since `PointToClient` gives me **relative** coordinates which **drastically** reduces the effort .... As an extension method it also is easy to use with all controls.

```
    /// <summary>
    ///   Is the mouse pointer over the control?
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = "control"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool IsMouseOverControl(this Control control)
    {
        if (control == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("control");
        Contract.EndContractBlock();

        Point pt = control.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
        return (pt.X >= 0 && pt.Y >= 0 && pt.X <= control.Width && pt.Y <= control.Height);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can declare:

```
bool insideMyControl = false;
```

Then trap MouseEnter (and set insideMyControl = true) and MouseLeave events (and set insideMyControl = false) on the particular control.
Then in your event look insideMyControl value.

Comment: beat me to it - I was going to say the same thing :)

Comment: @Jackson Pope: this morning it happened to me three times :)

Comment: This is almost a real time answer - thanks. One problem with this approach is, that I need to determine the position in another event of the same control. Unfortunately the order of the events is non deterministic. So it can happen the MouseLeave event is handled later (even only a very short time) and the result is not yet available.

Comment: @Horst Walter: sorry, I don't understand perfectly. The same control in which mouse enters/leave is responsible of another event, the one in which you have to complete the check?

Comment: Sorry, the details were missing to really understand the issue. I apologize. I have updated the question for better understanding...

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried [GetCursorPos](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetCursorPos.html) WIN32 API function

Try this.

```
Point p = new Point();
GetCursorPos(ref p);
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the problem was more to determine whether the cursor position is "over" my control. Since there is a way to get "relative" positions this is easy to determine. The key for me was the method control.PointToClient