# Detect if cursor is within the bounds of a control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a user control

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl, IMessageFilter
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
    }

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        var mouseLocation = Cursor.Position;

        if (Bounds.Contains(PointToClient(mouseLocation)))
        {
            bool aBool = true;//breakpoint
            bool two = aBool;//just assignment so compiler doesn't optimize my bool out
        }
        if (m.Msg != 0x20a) // Scrolling Message
        {
            return false;//ignore message
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I float over the user control contained in a parent form, the breakpoint is not hit.  The breakpoint is hit in close proximity, but I can be in an actual textbox inside the user control and not get a hit.  How can I accurately determine if I am within the bounds of this user control?

FWIW, I have two monitors.  It does not appear to make a difference which monitor I am using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cursor over WinForm control (c#, WinForm 4.0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620276/cursor-over-winform-control-c-winform-4-0)

Comment: @DanielA.White The answers I see in your link are specific to a single control.  Note that here I am hooking into a global message filter.  I don't think those will work.  Eventually I need to know exactly which control the mouse is over, not just the general user control which contains child controls.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try your hit testing against [`Control.ClientRectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientrectangle.aspx) rather than `Control.Bounds`:

```
if (ClientRectangle.Contains(PointToClient(Control.MousePosition))) {
    bool aBool = true;//breakpoint 
    bool two = aBool;
}
```

Comment: If this is from `MouseEventArgs` you can even just take the `Location` property from that, without the `PointToClient`.

Answer (score -3):

just for fast trick, You can trigger all userconrol's control with one event and handle the mouse over events.
for example if you had two textbox in your usercontrol

```
    textBox1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(controls_MouseMove);
    textBox2.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(controls_MouseMove);
    ...

    void controls_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Control subc=sender as Control;
        int mouseX = MousePosition.X;
        ....
    }
```

Comment: Base in mind that at least some controls fire the mousemove event when they receive a mouse-down event. The best way I found to deal with this is to double-check within the event handler of mouse move whether the mouse pointer is indeed outside the control.

Comment: MousePosition.X is the general position of the mouse in forms. If you have button inside panel, and panel is somewhere not in starting point of forms, this will give you invalid result